# Error con JSON.stringify()

Tags: php, jquery, cordova

estoy usando este codigo para un Login, del lado del servidor tengo un codigo en PHP, que con un echo me imprime ok o error, según el caso.

login.php

```
    <?php
 include "db_conn.php";
  if(isset($_POST['login'])){
            $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $pass = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            //VERIFICAMOS SI EXISTE EL USUARIO
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            $resp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            if(!$resp) {
                echo "error";
            }
            if(password_verify($pass, $resp['contrasenia'])){    
                echo "ok";
            }else{
               echo "error";
            }
```

y en mi index.html tengo el siguiente código.

```
function login(){
                var email = $.trim($("#email").val());
                var password = $.trim($("#password").val());
                var loginString ="email="+email+"&password="+password+"&login=";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    crossDomain: true, 
                    cache: false,
                    url: 'login.php',
                    data: JSON.stringify(loginString),
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data == "ok") {
                            console.log(data);
                            localStorage.loginstatus = true;
                            window.location.href = "inicio.html";
                        }
                        if(data == "error"){
                            swal("Error", "Datos incorrectos");
                            //alert('Error, datos incorrectos');
                            console.log(data);
                        }    
                        console.log(data);                    
                    },

                });
            }
```

funciona bien si en vez de poner

```
data: JSON.stringify(loginString)
```

pongo esto

```
data: loginString
```

en la consola me muestra lo siguiente:

```
(index):205 adding proxy for BarcodeScanner 
(index):205 adding proxy for Camera 
(index):205 errorerror
```

pero, al parecer tengo que usar el JSON.stringify, ya que como estoy haciendo una app con cordova, al momento de compilar la apk, no funciona el login, en el emulador y navegador si funciona, pero si compilo la apk, no funciona. Estuve leyendo y se supone que es por que necesito hacerlo con JSON.stringify.

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: pero `loginString` ya es un `string` no es un JSON

Answer (score 5):

No tengo claro si tienes que pasarle el login=, pero sugiero que tu var loginString
sea algo similar a esto:

`var loginString = { "email": email, "password":password , "login": }`

y luego en la llamada usa el JSON.stringify
`data: JSON.stringify(loginString)`

Comment: Ya lo hice y me devuelve esto: https://prnt.sc/q3hi0j , pero sigue sin funcionar el login, o al menos que le quite el JSON.stringify.

Comment: y si probamos ...    ```` var loginString = {};
        loginString.email = "aaa";
        loginString.password="bbb";
        loginString.login=""; ````
   
````JSON.stringify(loginString));````